# Popup notification for non-entry of values in input text

Tags: popup, pysimplegui

I have some input text boxes and buttons associated with them using pysimplegui. If the user click the button without entering anything or enter wrong type input, I want to create pop up message reminding the user to input correct data in input box. How to do it?

I have a input text box for entering area of land using PySimpleGUI. I have two buttons Hectare and Acre to decide the unit of area. When I click the Hectare button or Acre button without entering anything in text box, nothing happens. I want to create a pop up message to request the user to input the area first.

Answer (score 0):

Just to check the values for those input text boxes if they are valid as correct entries in the event loop when button event happened, call `sg.popup_ok` or other popup function to alarm if wrong entries.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

font = ("Courier New", 16, "bold")
sg.set_options(font=font)

layout = [
    [sg.Text('Width' ), sg.Push(), sg.Input('', size=25, key='Width')],
    [sg.Text('Height'), sg.Push(), sg.Input('', size=25, key='Height')],
    [sg.StatusBar('', size=(5, 1), expand_x=True, key='Status')],
    [sg.Push(), sg.Button('Area', bind_return_key=True), sg.Push()],
]
window = sg.Window('Demo', layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'Area':
        try:
            w, h = float(values['Width']), float(values['Height'])
        except ValueError:
            sg.popup_ok("Wrong input for Width/Height !!!")
            continue
        area = w*h
        window['Status'].update(int(area) if int(area)==area else area)

window.close()
```

Comment: Thank u. i am not calculating area. i put the extent of area directly and select the unit of area entered through Hectare and Acre buttons. then I will make calculations to calculate no of saplings in the given area. My problem is, if I click hectare or acre button without entering anything or enter non-numeric charactors  in the area box, nothing happens..... I want to have a pop-up message when there was empty area field or non-numeric charecters in area field.

Comment: Not to write a script same as your requirements, just a script to demo where and how to valid the inputs.